# The meaning of already (before and completion)

Tags: past-perfect, perfect-constructions

> I had **already** parked my bike near xyz when I saw the no parking sign.

Do I really need past perfect because of "already". Already mean 2 things first the **parking** came before the **seeing**(it is obvious) and that the first action is completed before the second happens. So if already mean these  2 things there is no need for  past perfect . Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what the sentence looks like without the past perfect:

> I already **parked** my bike near xyz when I saw the no parking sign.

This actually means something different.

*"I* ***had*** *parked"* means that the action of parking was complete when you saw the sign.

But *"I **parked** when I saw the sign"* sounds like you performed the action of parking *because* you saw the sign, or *at the same time* that you saw the sign.

*"I **already parked** when I saw the sign"* is confusing, because it mixes the two.  Remember that "I parked when I saw the sign" sounds like the sign was the reason why you parked, but *already* makes it confusing because it sounds like there is some other event that happened, but the sentence doesn't mention any other event.

We use "I already *simple-past-verb*" to mean something like "As of right now, I have completed the action of *simple-past-verb*."  For example, "I already ate" means that, talking about right now, I completed the action of eating earlier.  But in your sentence about parking, we're not talking from the viewpoint of right now, we're talking about two events that happened in the past, one before the other.  That's why the past perfect is clearer.